# Understanding DelayedInit

Tags: scala

I'm looking at `DelayedInit` in [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/) ...

*Comments are my understanding of the code.*

The following trait accepts a single argument, which is non-strictly evaluated (due to `=>`), and returns `Unit`. Its behavior is similar to that of a constructor.

```
trait DelayedInit {
  def delayedInit(x: => Unit): Unit
}
```

As I understand `App`, this trait has a `var x` that equals a function of 0-arity (no arguments). `x` gets assigned based on a call to the `delayedInit` method.

Then, `main` will call `apply '_()'` on `x` if it has a `Some(Function0[Unit])` type. If `x` is `None`, then nothing will happen.

```
trait App extends DelayedInit {
  var x: Option[Function0[Unit]] = None
  override def delayedInit(cons: => Unit) {
    x = Some(() => cons)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    x.foreach(_())
}
```

Then, I went to REPL per the book's examples:

```
scala> val x = new App { println("Now I'm initialized") }
x: java.lang.Object with App = $anon$1@2013b9fb
```

I saw that the output of ...

`scala> x.main(Array())`

was nothing.

Should the construction of an `App` instance result in calling `delayedInit` so that `x.main(Array())` returns the *constructor*-like behavior? Or, more concretely, should `Now I'm initialized` be expected to have printed out?

Comment: As Mauricio pointed out, when I did not include Scala in Depth's `DelayedInit`, `Now I'm initialized` printed out when I ran `x.main(Array())`. Besides his detailed answer below (thanks), the docs helped me out - http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.DelayedInit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you defined your own `DelayedInit` trait at the same file as `App`. If you did this, delete it, `DelayedInit` is a trait inside the `scala` package.

I just got the code from the book and pasted right into an Eclipse worksheet and it just works.

**EDIT**

What happens is that the code inside delayedInit gets called just before the constructor at the anonymous App object you are creating with new App { println("Now I'm initialized") }. You can see it at this screenshot:

[image: Worksheet showing the code being executed]

If you decide to remove this line:

```
x = Some(() => cons)
```

You will see that **Now I'm initialized** is never printed. Because the constructor code for the anonymous `App` object you are creating is given to the `delayedInit` method but is never run anywhere, so the `App`'s object constructor is never run.

Comment: does `it just works` mean that `Now I'm initialized` gets printed out when you call `x.main(Array())`? As I understand instantiation of the above `App` class, I don't see `delayedInit` getting called when creating the object. When creating the object, in Scala, functions (`def`'s) aren't automatically executed, as I understand.

Comment: Yes, it does, here's a screenshot of the worksheet - https://www.evernote.com/shard/s26/sh/11c17153-3f69-49a0-90c1-734dc5cd1cfb/ad773eac13a9ccc955e0dcadecfa0238

Comment: Upon object instantiation, how then does `delayedInit` get called to update `x`'s value? When a new `App` gets created, isn't this line only evaluated `var x: Option[Function0[Unit]] = None`?

Comment: What happens is that the code inside `delayedInit` gets called just **before** the constructor at the anonymous `App` object you are creating with `new App { println("Now I'm initialized") }`. More output - https://www.evernote.com/shard/s26/sh/d51d55b1-7556-4524-8264-f59c6d3177a4/4c6554f9dec031a702221dfe214b7465

Comment: so `{ println("Now I'm initialized") }` gets passed into the `delayedInit` method? [thanks for your help, Mauricio]

Comment: Yes, if you comment `x = Some(() => cons)` you will see that `Now I'm initialized` is never printed.

Comment: Could you please update answer with your helpful comments and I'll accept?

Comment: Updated the answer with the comments now.